# How to fire Local Notifications always at specific time

Tags: ios, swift2, uidatepicker

Is it possible to fire Local Notifications always at specific time (i.e at 12:00am local time) if user has picked the date from UIDatePicker?

i.e User is able to select only the date (dd,MM,yyyy) from a UIDatePicker:

```
 let dateEnteredByDatePicker = datePicker.date
```

How would I change the HH:mm to the specific ones that I want?